# Not able to import maven dependencies in eclipse ? Tried everything

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am using apache maven 3.6.3(not the embedded one in eclipse).
I have tried the same with the embedded maven also , still facing the same error.

Also i have deleted the whole m2 repository and again re-import the whole project but still the maven dependencies are not installing.

[image: Installations]

Maven dependencies

[image: Maven dependencies]

Comment: Can you share more details.Which dependencies are not getting downloded.What error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming windows and as other answer you have a pom.xml:

1. Delete your repository at C:/Users/????/.m2/repository
2. Check your C:/Users/????/.m2/settings.xml for correct [proxy config](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)
3. Set you M2_HOME environment variable to <MAVEN INSTALL DIR
4. Add %M2_HOME%/bin: to your PATH variable assuming windows (remember to start a new window after changing environment variables)
5. Try a mvn clean install from the command line - GET THIS WORKING FIRST
6. Then try from eclipse, you do not need a proxy setting it should call the default mvn.

Comment: dont have any settings.xml file in C:/Users/????/.m2/settings.xml.

Comment: use the [default](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) to start, the only thing you may need to add is the proxy if you're behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your project to maven project pom.xml will be automatically created,if not
1- Create pom.xml file -by clicking on project directory->new->file
2- search from google maven dependencies for ex: if you want to download spring-context.jar ,then search for maven spring context ,you will get groupid and artifactid paste it in pom.xml file.jars will be automatically downloaded.